# Browserify - mock module for production build

Tags: browserify

I'm trying to google out how to mock some module for production in browserify.

For example i have a logger module written by myself.

It is required in some application modules/react components.

And i wonder how to replace it with some mock module in production build (i'm using gulp), just to prevent logs to be visible in production.

Is there any common solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can either stub it out by hand or use a mocking library such as [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org).

Then at runtime, your logging module can return the original logger or the stubbed-out version depending on a flag which you can set to Debug or Release mode.